# Can't download the ZIP file of CWM Recovery from its official site, why?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

I recently found an old phone (Samsung Galaxy S2) and wanted to download the fitting ClockworkMod Recovery.

Well, when searching for the .zip files on http://clockworkmod.com, I found out that something changed.

What happened to CWM? Why aren't the .zip files not accessible anymore through the browser, and how can I get them anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discontinued since 6.0.5.1.

There should still be (many) copies scattered around the web, including PhilZ ones, but it's still suggested to switch to TWRP as it's actively maintained, especially if you want to flash KitKat and above.

Comment: Flashing TWRP would be an option and I already recognized it if it wouldn't need SecRec (or something like that) in the system which isn't supported with the stock firmware of named smartphone

Comment: @Ov3rfl0w IsoRec, right? Indeed... I found this one on CM's wiki guide for i9100 (yours is an i9100, right?): [link](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934516900), hopefully it's usable.